# After a while, /etc/resolv.conf stops using /etc/netns/X/resolv.conf

Tags: linux-networking, network-namespace

My setup:

- `/etc/ns-shared-resolv.conf` is written to regularly with `nameserver x.x.x.x`, updated from a script
- `/etc/netns/ag2/resolv.conf` is a symlink to the above (along with `ag3`, `ag4`).. for central DNS settings in root netns**o**
- Long-running service running in `ag2` netns (via `ip netns exec ag2 ...`, launched from a `systemd` service)

What happens:

Everything works fine.. for some arbitrary number of hours. After that, DNS requests fail. Using `tcpdump` I can see DNS requests going to "the wrong place" .. the DNS server in root `/etc/resolv.conf`, NOT the netns one.

At the same time while that's not working, `ip netns exec ag2 cat /etc/resolv.conf` works to show the correct settings.

If I start a new `ip netns exec ag2 bash` shell, it gets the "correct" `resolv.conf` (symlink to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`, which is updated "live" with the contents of `ns-shared-resolv.conf`)

So it's like after a while, long-running processes get the root `resolv.conf`?

Questions:

1. Why is this happening / how can I diagnose how it's using the "wrong" resolv.conf / DNS server after this ranmdom amount of time?
2. Can I just somehow get the ubuntu default DNS `systemd-resolv` server working within netns-es so I don't need to do this craziness?

Edit: like this person! --> https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/dnh8wq/comment/fo1tbty/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Answer (score 1):

## Explanation

When you put a file in `/etc/netns/.../resolv.conf`, it will cause `ip netns exec` to bind mount it over `/etc/resolv.conf` when setting up the namespace set up.

This usually works, but when an atomic replacement of `/etc/resolv.conf` occurs, the inode that the bind mount is on top of changes. I haven't confirmed exactly why this is, but I'd venture to guess rather than overlaying on top of whatever file happens to exist, bind mounting over a file actually attaches to the inode and not just the filename.

When you have something like NetworkManager or resolvconf managing your `/etc/resolv.conf`, this will lead to the bind mount mysteriously disappearing when those tools replace the file to do an atomic update.

This is most likely the cause for why your `resolv.conf` is being overwritten.

## Workarounds

There are a couple approaches to resolving this:

1. You can disable anything from updating your /etc/resolv.conf, and opt to manage it yourself. (One of the [other answers](https://serverfault.com/a/1127271/209611) here points out how to disable it with NetworkManager.)
2. You can (and probably should) force outgoing UDP and TCP connections on port 53 to get sent to your DNS server of choice rather. This will effectively override the `/etc/resolv.conf`. It's pretty easy to do this with iptables, doing something like:

   ```bash
   ip netns exec "${NAMESPACE}" iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to "${NAMESERVER}"
   ip netns exec "${NAMESPACE}" iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to "${NAMESERVER}"
   ```

   (Where `${NAMESPACE}` is the namespace and `${NAMESERVER}` is the DNS server you wish to force. Note that this breaks failover.)

   (Please feel free to update this answer with information about how to do this with other firewall tools like nftables. I don't personally know, so I'd rather not.)

   Although this method is not persistent across reboots, at least with iptables, it is part of the state of the network namespace itself, so it is persistent when entering into the netns with multiple `ip netns exec` commands.

## Troubleshooting

You should make sure that this is actually working correctly, as there are several other ways in which your DNS can leak inside of `ip netns exec`. To completely clean up DNS leaks, you will need to ensure that DNS resolution always happens inside of the netns.

### systemd-resolved

If you are using systemd-resolved, it may be necessary to ensure it is blocked or disabled inside of the namespace. glibc's choice to use systemd resolved can be influenced by 1. `/etc/resolve.conf`, where systemd-resolved may set itself as the resolver using something along the lines of `nameserver 127.0.0.1:53` (which will be overridden by `ip exec netns` without needing to do anything) or, 2. `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, a file read by glibc to determine which [NSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch) modules to use when resolving names. In general, if the `hosts:` line contains `resolve`, systemd-resolved is in use. If it only contains other entries, it most likely does not. Traditional DNS resolution, using the nameserver at `/etc/resolv.conf`, occurs via the `dns` module.

One possible workaround would be to add a file at `/etc/netns/${NAMESPACE}/nsswitch.conf` with something like:

```
...
hosts: dns
...
```

(where the `...` segments are your original `/etc/nsswitch.conf` settings.)

Unlike `/etc/resolv.conf`, this file is not regularly written to, so this bind mount should not go stale.

### nscd

If you are not using systemd-resolved, there is one other way in which glibc may apparently ignore your `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/nsswitch.conf` setup. This is when nscd is running. glibc will try to reach nscd at `/var/run/nscd/socket` before it starts loading NSS modules. In NixOS, this is used to avoid needing to pollute the global state configuration of NSS modules into the direct runtime environment of every process; it relies on nscd loading all of the NSS modules and other processes resolving via nscd. In some other systems, nscd may be used to provide caching of resolution.

There are several workarounds:

1. You can unshare the filesystem namespace and bind mount something, e.g. `/var/empty`, over `/var/run/nscd`. This will disable `nscd` for just one process. Note that this has to be done separately from the netns configuration; it will not persist merely by calling `ip netns exec`.
2. You can [use firejail](https://vtimofeenko.com/posts/wireguard-namespace-flake/) to leverage the power of seccomp-bpf to disallow access to `/var/run/nscd/socket`. This might look something like this:

   ```bash
   firejail --noprofile --blacklist=/var/run/nscd/socket --netns=${NAMESPACE} --dns=${NAMESERVER} [command]
   ```
3. In many cases, you can just disable nscd globally, as it is not generally needed. This is not generally recommended on NixOS, but is reasonable on most Linux based operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was caused by NetworkManager, and disabling nm's resolv.conf handling fixed it.

Make a file /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/90-dns-none.conf :

```ini
[main]
dns=none
```

and restart NetworkManager.